# Everytime we restart the Linux server it looks like the root gets a new password hash

Tags: passwords, hashing, linux

The other day I was asked by a friend to change their forgotten root password of their Linux server.

I have done this procedure many times without a problem, but this time something strange happened and I need an explanation for it.

**What I did :**

**1.** Restarted the server and went to the single mode, again I was asked for root password for maintenance.

**2.** Restarted the server one more time and added `init=/bin/bash` to the end of boot option, and got a shell quickly (Thought, I almost did the job).

**3.** I used `mount -o remount remount, rw/` to be able to write to the disk.

**4.** Then I changed the root password with `passwd` command and *got the message that password was updated successfully*.

**5.** Rebooted the system (I did by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del).

**6.** Tried the new root password, it was rejected as a wrong password. I have tried few times. No luck.

**7.** Again did the previous procedure and modified the passwd file, created a new user without a password `(new_user::0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash)`, saved the file and tried again. Again the wrong password was reported !!! (Did not expect to be asked to enter a pssword as `new_user` does not have a password)

**8.** Opened the shadow file and put a hash that I knew the value for `new_user`. Then I saved the file. I clearly see that system confirmed the changes have been written to the file, tried again. No luck.

**9.** Went to the shadow file again, another surprise: The value that I put for `new_user` wasn't there. I don't understand why, as I saw the confirmation that the file was modified in `Nano` editor.

**10.** I have restarted the system and checked the shadow file again. Here I realized that the hash for the original root user each time I restart the system, changes !!!

Probably that is the reason I am not able to change the root password, but how this happened, each time I do restart the server it looks like I have to deal with a new hash `(Coluld it be a lock or something on shadow file ?)` . I am not getting what's going on.

**Finally decided to roll back the changes**, so I went to the `passwd` file and deleted the line that I added for `new_user` (again got confirmation of changes), but after restarting the server I checked the `passwd` file and the user was still there. I was not able to write to shadow file, but one time that I wrote to passwd file I was not able to remove it.

Please help me to understand the issue.

Comment: Is this a cloud server? It sounds like the cloud infrastructure is doing this.

Comment: @paj28 No this is not a cloud server , just a server inside the campus that acts as a webserver as well as a dataserver , it has an app that gets the student information from an admin account and other user can access the information . It's not even connected to intenet .

Comment: Possibly the disk is failing? Writes happen in memory, so appear correct from the disk cache, but aren't actually written to disk? I had that happen with an Raspberry Pi and its SD card.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder Colud you please tell me what are the causes of disk failure ? I need to mention if i boot the server everything works just fine and there is no sign of disk failure . Is it possible in normal boot it doees not fail but in single mode it does?

Comment: Did you `sync` between steps 4 and 5?

Comment: @user1686 No I did not , could that be the issue ? is it possbile that even system confirmed the password change , without `sync ` won't apply the change ? Could you please tell me the proper way to `sync ` after using `passwd `command

Comment: It's not about "after passwd", but rather about "before rebooting, if you do not have a working init system". A `sync` just flushes all buffered changes to disk (like ejecting a USB drive) – normally it's done by init as part of the reboot process, but when booting with init=/bin/sh you don't have that anymore (without init, ctrl-alt-del is like pulling the plug), therefore any file modifications that are buffered in memory will be lost when you force a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

1. `sync` - Run `sync` after doing modifications, before rebooting. It's possible that the changes are only in the disk-cache, and the lack of a proper init is causing the changes not to be written back.
2. Read-only disk failure: Some flash-based systems can fail, such that they are read-only. I've experienced it with an SD card, but maybe also SSDs could suffer from this. But if the machine is working normally when booted normally, this doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot